# How to open all links on a mouseover event in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried this:

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++) {

document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].onmouseover= eval(function(){
window.open(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].href, "_blank");});
}
```

But it went wrong when reaching this part of the code: "window.open(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].href"

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined "

EDIT 1:

I also tried this:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onmouseover = function(){window.open(links[i].href, "_blank")};
}
```

I got the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined

When I change 'i' to 'i-1' for window.open every single link gets replaced with the last link on the page, see code:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onmouseover = function(){window.open(links[i-1].href, "_blank")};
}
```

Comment: have you tried storing the links in an array first like `var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');` then iterated through the array?  It worked fine for me.

Comment: have you tried setting the mouseover event with addEventListener?.  You could do [document.onDOMContentLoaded](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded) set for each link element...

Comment: Any clue how to just fix the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined error easily? I don't want to pass the highest/last-one-in-array i-value for every link that needs to be opened with window.open.

Comment: Take the function(i) after onmouseover and replace it with just `function() { ...}` .  (Take the "i" out as a parameter) .That just worked for me.  If not, comment and Ill run something to help figure it out

Comment: No, it does not work as expected. See edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as expected:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onmouseover = (
        function(h){
            return function(){ window.open(h, "_blank") }
        }
    )(links[i].href);
}
```

Comment: Interesting javascript syntax. Could you explain what code that means, please? Do you have any links to references that show that you can pass "links[i].href" this way: {window.open(h, "_blank")} })(links[i].href)

Comment: Your initial problem is that the i variable is from outer-scope. Its value is and remains 'links.length' after the loop, for each created event handler. The above code is passing link[i].href to the h parameter of a temporary function which is immediately executed and returns the event handler. This way, each event handler is assigned a different value of h in its own scope. You should search "javascript closures" for some articles about this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are getting `Unable to get href of ......` is because the element is probably because the element is not YET defined. This means you should put the code at the end or add it to  `window.onload` - using `addEventListener` instead of `onload`.

Well, @Arnauld's answer is probably good enough, but I suggest to use `addEventListener` and `attachEvent`, because it can probably make your coding easier :)

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    if(links[i].addEventListener){ // Check if addEventListener is available
        links[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            window.open(links[i].href, "_blank");
        });
    }else{
        if(links[i].attachEvent){ // addEventListener not available; test attachEvent
            links[i].attachEvent("onmouseover", function(){
                window.open(links[i].href, "_blank");
            });
        }else{
            // Neither attachEvent nor addEventListener is available; Throw error (You can try to use links[i].onmouseover)
            throw new Error("!(addEventListener & attachEvent)");
        }
    }
}
```